# how to read files from a folder?the folder contains different type of file names?

Tags: c++, c

folder name sample and files are like

```
1.text  
1_1.text , 
1_2.text, 
1_3.text,
3.text, 
4_1.text
```

we have trouble on reading  from different files.

Code:

```
if(dir!=NULL) { 
   while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL) { 
          printf(dent->d_name); 
          count++; 
   } 
}
```

I am getting file names from that. but how can i store the files and how can i get the data from all files

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And what platform (operating system) are you targeting?

Comment: What is the trouble? Where is failing code?

Comment: That's sad. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you using the absolute path.

Comment: Does folder contains other files too?

Comment: if(dir!=NULL)   {
        while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL)  {
     printf(dent->d_name); count++;
 }
   }
i am getting file names from that. but how can i store the files and how can i get the data from all files.

Comment: Okay, you are using `readdir` which points to a POSIX system (like Linux or OSX). Now do you want to use C++ or C? In C++ you can store file information in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), in C there are no such ready collections. The solution is therefore very different depending on which language you choose.

Comment: You have to open a file with filename and read from it.

Comment: i am getting  . ..    files with my files(1.text 1_1.text  etc ). when read the data dynamically . file is going to infinite loop. how can i skip first two(. , .. )files.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand your code and open the files with [c](/questions/tagged/c) [`fopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

```
if(dir!=NULL) { 
    while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL) { 
        FILE *fp = fopen(dent->d_name, "r");
        /* process file */
        fclose(fp);
   } 
}
```

or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/)

```
if(dir!=NULL) { 
    while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL) { 
        ifstream f(dent->d_name);
        /* process file */
   } 
}
```

If you're on Unix, you can use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to verify, that `dent->d_name` is indeed a file and not a directory or some special file.

Comment: A warning to the OP: You should check that the "file" you get from `readdir` is actually a file, and not something else, before you open the file for reading.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Very good point! Thank you.